# Melt command: how to read video properties?

Tags: video, mlt

How to read the total number of frames from a video with "melt" command
Same for time and frames per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible answer to get the properties in a XML format.

Use: `melt movie.flv -consumer xml`

Code for php:

```
//get total frames and framerate

ob_start();
system('melt '.$video.' -consumer xml');
$clip_prop = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$xml_prop = new DOMDocument();
$xml_prop->loadXML( $clip_prop );

$properties = $xml_prop->getElementsByTagName("property");

foreach( $properties as $property )
{
     $attribute = $property->getAttribute("name");
     //for total frames
     if( $attribute == "length" )
          $frames = $property->nodeValue;
     //for frame rates
     if( $attribute == "meta.media.0.stream.frame_rate" )
          $fps = $property->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Florin you could also do it with the command line and some dirty grep:

```
melt AAG_5766.MOV -consumer xml | grep length | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
```